# Update array inside the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have used an array of objects which contains questions and answers as array. Whenever I have selected the options(checkbox), I will store it another array `options_selected` and push it into the array of objects based on `question_id`. The first question was stored successfully with its options. When I add second question and update the options, the answers not updated correctly.

Initialize as
`const [selectedAnswers, setSelectedAnswers] = useState([])`

the select function is

```
const onSelectAnswers = (item, options) => {
    console.log('item.question_id', item.question_id)
    console.log('option_id', options.option_id)

    if (selectedAnswers && selectedAnswers.length > 0) {
      selectedAnswers.map(ansData => {
        if (ansData.question_id == item.question_id) {
          if (!ansData.options_selected.includes(options.option_id)) {
            ansData.options_selected.push(options.option_id)
          } else {
            ansData.options_selected.splice(ansData.options_selected.indexOf(options.option_id), 1)
          }
        } else {
          console.log('NotEqualLoop')
          let temp = []
          temp.push(options.option_id)
          
          item['options_selected'] = temp
          selectedAnswers.push(item)
        }
      })
    } else {
      console.log('Initial_empty_array')
      let temp = []
      temp.push(options.option_id)
      
      item['options_selected'] = temp
      selectedAnswers.push(item)
    }
    
    console.log('selectedAnswers===>', JSON.stringify(selectedAnswers))
  }
```

The first time with single question, it works well. But more than one question not working well.

The response is

```
[
  {
    "type": "MCQ_TEXT",
    "question_id": "0e1be959-9c66-4b29-9e6c-9c2aed914ac1",
    "question": "From the interventions and assessments listed below, please identify pressure injury related intervention(s) and assessment(s) conducted on admission.",
    "options": [
      {
        "value": "1. Skin Assessment",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2. Nutritional Screening",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "value": "3. Functional Status",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "value": "4. Identify Discharge Planning Concern",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "4"
      }
    ],
    "options_selected": [
      "1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "MCQ_TEXT",
    "question_id": "1009f987-3ae3-483b-957e-a56e084b9b17",
    "question": "Sample Question 2",
    "options": [
      {
        "value": "1. Skin Assessment",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2. Nutritional Screening",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "value": "3. Functional Status",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "value": "4. Identify Discharge Planning Concern",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "4"
      }
    ],
    "options_selected": [
      "1"
    ]
  }
]
```

When update the second question options, it will added again with empty `options_selected`. The response is

```
[
  {
    "type": "MCQ_TEXT",
    "question_id": "0e1be959-9c66-4b29-9e6c-9c2aed914ac1",
    "question": "From the interventions and assessments listed below, please identify pressure injury related intervention(s) and assessment(s) conducted on admission.",
    "options": [
      {
        "value": "1. Skin Assessment",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2. Nutritional Screening",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "value": "3. Functional Status",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "value": "4. Identify Discharge Planning Concern",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "4"
      }
    ],
    "options_selected": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "MCQ_TEXT",
    "question_id": "1009f987-3ae3-483b-957e-a56e084b9b17",
    "question": "Sample Question 2",
    "options": [
      {
        "value": "1. Skin Assessment",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2. Nutritional Screening",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "value": "3. Functional Status",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "value": "4. Identify Discharge Planning Concern",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "4"
      }
    ],
    "options_selected": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "MCQ_TEXT",
    "question_id": "1009f987-3ae3-483b-957e-a56e084b9b17",
    "question": "Sample Question 2",
    "options": [
      {
        "value": "1. Skin Assessment",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "value": "2. Nutritional Screening",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "2"
      },
      {
        "value": "3. Functional Status",
        "correct": true,
        "option_id": "3"
      },
      {
        "value": "4. Identify Discharge Planning Concern",
        "correct": false,
        "option_id": "4"
      }
    ],
    "options_selected": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't know how to handle the `map` function properly.
Advance Thanks for your Time.

Comment: It looks to me like the body of your map does not return anything and you do not use the map method's return value either, so it seems to me like you might as well use `Array.prototype.forEach()` for what you are trying to accomplish. Side-note: for both map and forEach you have three available parameters available in the anonymous inner function: the current element, its index and the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ::

```
const [extra,setExtra]=useState(0) // add this

const onSelectAnswers = (item, options) => {
    console.log('item.question_id', item.question_id)
    console.log('option_id', options.option_id)

    if (selectedAnswers && selectedAnswers.length > 0) {
      selectedAnswers.map(ansData => {
        if (ansData.question_id == item.question_id) {
          if (!ansData.options_selected.includes(options.option_id)) {
            ansData.options_selected.push(options.option_id)
            setExtra(extra+1) // add this
          } else {
    ansData.options_selected.splice(ansData.options_selected.indexOf(options.option_id), 
          }
        } else {
          console.log('NotEqualLoop')
          let temp = []
          temp.push(options.option_id)
          setExtra(extra+1) // add this

          item['options_selected'] = temp
          selectedAnswers.push(item)
          setExtra(extra+1) // add this
        }
      })
    } else {
      console.log('Initial_empty_array')
      let temp = []
      temp.push(options.option_id)
      setExtra(extra+1) // add this

      item['options_selected'] = temp
      selectedAnswers.push(item)
      setExtra(extra+1) // add this
    }
    
    console.log('selectedAnswers===>', JSON.stringify(selectedAnswers))
  }
```